# Excel Chart Scatter Straight Line and show length based on 3rd series

Tags: excel, excel-charts

I'm trying to create a scatter straight line chart to visually show how a retaining wall looks in elevation view. I have a top of wall dimension and bottom of wall dimension and the length of each wall section. I am able to use the top and bottom of wall dimension but having trouble showing the length of the run. I have tried to add the wall length as another data point, but doesn't work, it just skews the other two points. Tried to use a cumulative run length, helper column, but couldn't get that value to populate the x axis properly. I added some notes in red in the image below. Spent a few hours and appreciate any help.
[image: retaining wall scatter straight line chart]

Answer (score 0):

I perhaps wouldn't use excel for diagramming this, but I think you would need to add more points and interpolate the values. If your minimum wall length is 25, then you could use 25 as your base. Wall 1 is 100, so you need 4 points (100 / 25). Wall 3 is 150 so you need 6 points. *Plus 1 point for each wall to accommodate start/stop.*

For missing values in wall 1 top, you would take (230-224.3)/4 = 1.425. Then add 1.425 to the value above it.

It would look something like this:

[image]

And this would need to be a line chart, where column A can represent the X-axis for labeling.

Comment: Very helpful and creative. I'll try it.